# Como funciona exatamente o return Javascript

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como ele funciona exatamente, onde é necessário usar dentro de algum escopo como if etc.

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor o que você *não* entende no `return`?

Comment: Era sobre a questão de blocos como if, mas foi esclarecida.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Como diz esta [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), o `return`:

- **Define o valor retornado por uma função. Quando não há um valor especificado, `undefined` será retornado.**
- **Interrompe a execução da função atual.**

### Retorno com valor

```js
function retornaValor() {
    return 1;
}
console.log(retornaValor());
```

O código acima imprime `1` no console.

### Retorno sem valor

```js
function retornoVazio() {
    return;
}
console.log(retornoVazio());
```

O código acima imprime `undefined` no console.

### Retorno fora de função (global)

Por outro lado, se você tentar usar o `return` fora de uma função, num código executado num navegador, receberá um erro. Por exemplo, no Chrome, obtive:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

### Retorno de bloco `{}`

Mesmo se usado dentro de um bloco de código, o `return` irá finalizar a função atual ou causar o erro como já descrito. Não existe o conceito de retorno de um bloco. Exemplo

```js
function f(val) {
    if (val) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}
```

O código acima irá retornar 1 ou 2 para a função, independendo das chaves.

### Quanto e como usar o `return`

Algumas pessoas acreditam que cada método/função deve ter um ponto de saída único. Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```js
function f(a, cond) {
    if (cond) {
        return -2;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 1) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Esta função é pequena, mas logo podem surgir dezenas condições e `returns`, tornando o código difícil de entender.

Uma alternativa seria a seguinte:

```js
function f(a, cond) {
    val retorno = cond ? -2 : -1;
    if (!cond) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == 1) {
                retorno = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Obviamente é uma questão de opinião pessoal. Particularmente, eu acredito que o problema está em criar uma lógica clara e não na quantidade de `returns`.

#### [Veja os exemplos no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm6C9/)

Comment: Acho que vale a pena citar que o javascript é capaz de interromper o postback, ou submit, da página quando o mesmo retorna false.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck A pergunta não é sobre eventos.

Comment: De qualquer forma não custa nada você incluir esta informação na sua resposta, só pra deixa-la bem completa.

Comment: Então, tem quem ache que a função tem que ter apenas um ponto de saída. Tem quem ache que um comportamento padrão deve ser definido e os ifs com return são usados como condições de guarda (para exceções no fluxo do código (não confundir com Exceptions)). Eu concordo com o segundo tipo de programador. PS: `else` dá cancer, `return` é o caminho.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Eu até cheguei a escrever sobre isso, na verdade sobre manipulação de eventos em geral, mas ficou destoante porque não acrescenta nada em relação ao `return`, apenas detalhes sobre uma funcionalidade específica e um valor de retorno específico. Eu teria que começar a explicar o contexto sobre a manipulação de eventos e *bubbling*. Mais uma coisa: [*postback*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback) não é exatamente um [sinônimo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) de *submit*.

Comment: @utluiz Claro, eu sei. Em nenhum momento eu quis dizer que Postback == Submit. Se me fiz entender assim não foi minha intenção.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode utilizar o `return` para 2 tipos de situações.

**1. Retornar um valor.**
 **2. Parar o fluxo de execução da função atual.**

**1.** A situação do uso é quando você precisa validar, calcular ou modular o código.

```
function Calculadora(valor1, valor2, operacao) {
   var resultado = 0;

   if (operacao == "+")
       resultado = Soma(valor1, valor2);
   // ...   

   return resultado;
}

function Soma(valor1, valor2) {
   return parseInt(valor1) + parseInt(valor2);
}
```

**2.** A situação do uso é quando você não precisa mais continuar executando a função atual, o resultado dela já está determinado.

```
function ExibeValor(valor) // código apenas didático, sim é feio.
{
   if (parseInt(valor) <= 10) {
      alert('O valor é menor/igual a 10.');
      return;
   }

   if (parseInt(valor) > 10 && parseInt(valor) <= 20) {
      alert('O valor é maior que 10 e menor/igual a 20.');
      return;
   }

   if (parseInt(valor) > 20 && parseInt(valor) <= 30) {
      alert('O valor é maior que 20 e menor/igual a 30.');
      return;
   }

   if (parseInt(valor) > 30 && parseInt(valor) <= 40) {
      alert('O valor é maior que 30 e menor/igual a 40.');
      return;
   }
}
```

Vamos supor que você chame a função passando o **valor `5`**, você vai entrar no 1° `if` e pronto você não precisa executar todos outros `if` pra saber o retorno da função. Com isso você melhora o tempo de execução e fica menos custoso o processamento.

Answer (score 0):

O return no javascript é semelhando ao return em Java e C#, que são as linguagens que eu tenho conhecimento, já no Delphi o return pelo pouco que conheço funciona de maneira diferente
, sendo que ao passar por um return em javascript a function (ou o escopo atual) é abortado não prosseguindo no fluxo, e retornando o valor ao seu invocador, esse comportamento pode ser percebido também utilizando um debug no navegador como o [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), ou o nativo do Google Chrome

```
function TesteRetorno(param){
if(param > 50){
    return "Maior que 50";
}
if(param > 10){
    return "Maior que 10";
}
return "Menor que 10";
}
alert(TesteRetorno(2));
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/7WhCy/)

Comment: O delphi não tem return. É Result := ou nome_da_função := .

Comment: Sim, sim se chama Result, correto é que se ele é programador Dephi com certeza deve está pensando no escopo do Result do Delphi.

Comment: Tem o `exit`, mas sem retornar valor. Um equivalente ao `return` do Javascript no Delphi, seria: `Result := <valor>; exit;`

Comment: Errado novamente, o exit pode retornar valor sim senhor a partir de versões como o 2010. exit(1) por exemplo retorna 1.

Comment: ok, ok, só citei Delphi em minha resposta pois já vi amigos que confundem o return do javascript pelo fato de serem familiarizados com o Result do Delphi, dando o return e achando que o código que vem após será executado, o que não acontece no caso do javascript.